# I'm not sure why I'm getting a TypeError (float object cannot be interpreted as integer) in this code:

Tags: python, typeerror

Following the Think Python textbook (second edition).

Trying to get past this one section but repeatedly running into an error that seems very confusing to me, as I've simply copied the code from the book.

```
import turtle
def polygon(t, length, n):
    for i in range(n):
    t.fd(length)
    t.lt(360/n)
import math
def circle(t, r):
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
    n = int(circumference/3) + 3
    length = circumference/n
    polygon(t, n, length)

bob=turtle.Turtle()
circle(bob, 100)
```

When I do this I end getting an error code:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`.... circle(bob, 100)`

`... polygon(t, n, length)`

`... for i in range(n):`

`... TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

I've seen other similar questions on stackoverflow about this section but I haven't seen anyone with a Type Error before. I think this section of the book must be written in a kind of confusing way since people seem to be making a lot of errors here, and I've definitely struggled with trying to follow what code goes with what code and what code explicitly does not.

[This is the book, by the way](https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/thinkpython2.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've swapped the parameters `n` and `length` in the call to `polygon`. So inside of `polygon`, you call `range()` on a float. That leads to the type error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That seems very non-intuitive, since everything is labeled and named, but I'll certainly be sure to keep things in the same order in the future. This has been plaguing me for a day and a half so I really appreciate the help, I never would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: If you want to pass by name without considering the order, you need keyword arguments (kwargs for short). `polygon(t=t, n=n, length=length)` will also work.